# Fetching JSON data after implementing JSON web service

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am learning Swift on Udemy and JSON data parsing has me struggling. I have created two files `WebService.swift` and `OrderListViewModel.swift`. Former is... as name suggests implementing the data request (node.js) from Glitch while later is implementing View Model. Here are the files:

```
`WebService.swift`:



import Foundation

class Webservice {

    func getAllOrders(completion: @escaping ([Order]?) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://island-bramble.glitch.me/orders") else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  completion(nil)
                }

                return

            }


            let orders = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Order].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(orders)
            }

       }.resume()

    }
}
```

I reasonably understand what's happening here. I am unable to understand the part that's happening below.

```
`OrderListViewModel.swift`:

import Foundation


    class OrderListViewModel: ObservableObject {


        var orders = [OrderViewModel]()

        init() {
            fetchOrders()
        }
        func fetchOrders() {

            Webservice().getAllOrders { orders in
                if let orders = orders {
                    self.orders = orders.map(OrderViewModel.init)
            }

            }
        }
    }

    class OrderViewModel {

        let id = UUID()

        var order: Order
        init (order: Order) {
            self.order = order
        }
        var name: String {
            return self.order.name
        }
        var size: String {
            return self.order.size
        }
        var coffeeName: String {
            return self.order.coffeeName
        }
        var total: Double {
            return self.order.total
        }
    }
```

How is `fetchOrders()` fetching `orders`. More specifically how is this block of code (closure) fetching the `orders`? Alternatively, if data fetched from remote server is passed as arguments to the callback function’s parameters how is below code retrieving it?

```
 Webservice().getAllOrders { orders in
                if let orders = orders {
                    self.orders = orders.map(OrderViewModel.init)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a function

`Webservice().getAllOrders`

and pass a completion block

```
{ orders in
    if let orders = orders {
          self.orders = orders.map(OrderViewModel.init)
}
```

into it.

Completion block will receive value named `orders` of type `[Order]?`

and if `orders` is not `nil`

```
if let orders = orders
```

You can assign your class var `orders`, which is declared here

`var orders = [OrderViewModel]`

to new array which in turn contains elements of type `OrderViewModel`

The latter is the result of

`orders.map(OrderViewModel.init)`

and this can also be written like

```
orders.forEach { order in 
      self.orders.append(OrderViewModel.init(order))
}
```